# Filter a value when using regex and grep

Tags: android, regex, bash, shell, grep

I am reading memory usage for an android app named `mobile_cep` as follows

`adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep`

But this command this output as

```
amar@admin:~/Desktop/bash-andy$ adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep
234,467K: org.carleton.iot.mobile_cep (pid 27060 / activities)
234,467K: org.carleton.iot.mobile_cep (pid 27060 / activities)
```

meaning that output is displayed twice. My goal is to find `234,467K` value multiple times so as to find the average value of memory usage.

The following script is used

```
#!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
        ((counter++))
        val1=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep | sed 's/:.*//')
        echo $val1
    done
echo  done
```

It gives the result as

```
234,675K 234,675K
234,678K 234,678K
234,679K 234,679K
234,678K 234,678K
234,679K 234,679K
234,682K 234,682K
```

But I just want first value.

---

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Why did you accept your first question, when it was not solving the problem yet. You should have waited and responded till it was solving your problem

Comment: What does `K` stand for? is that the value multiplied by `1024` or `1000`,  you want to convert that or just want the averaged value in `K` also?

Comment: i would see `man cut`

Answer (score -1):

The issue was solved using following code

```
 #!/bin/bash
counter=1
while [ $counter -le 10 ]
    do
        ((counter++))
        data=$(adb shell dumpsys meminfo | grep mobile_cep | sed 's/:.*//')
        List=$(echo $data | tr " " "\n")
        current=($List)
        tuple=${current[0]}
        currentMemory=$(sed 's|[K,]||g' <<< $tuple)
        echo $currentMemory
    done
echo  done
    echo  done
```

it gives output as

```
234675 
234678 
234679 
234678 
234679
234682
```

Comment: It's my first bash script, what do u expect. Can you provide an efficient solution?

Comment: No, it has all the same issues as the one in your answer. Yes, you could get an efficient solution in this forum but so far I at least have no idea what it is you're trying to do - what's in your question (a loop calling the same command 10 times immediately one after the other) just doesn't make sense as far as I can tell and idk what the output of `adb` is before the greps, nor how `234,467K` factors into it nor what the expected output would be or why. Go back to your original question and fix it or write a brand new, complete question that explains why the original Q&A wasn't adequate.

Comment: Yes the loop is calling same command till the app is running as i want to find average memory consumption for an experimental runtime.234 mb is the instantaneous memory used by the specified application.

Comment: I am sorry if u felt that way but it was not to hurt your feelings. I have a lot of respect for all the persons that help one another on this platform. And yes, I am not that familiar with bash scripting and its a new area for me.

Comment: No problem, if you want help just read what I said in my comment and see [ask] if that's not clear.